# Delete all custom properties from selected object?

Tags: properties, custom-properties

Seen bunch of threads for deleting every custom property from the whole scene, but not for the currently selected object. Or selected objects.

Answer (score 0):

Enter `for ob in C.selected_objects: ob.id_properties_clear()` into the Python console and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> twice.